# Why am I getting a 'Numeric value not recognized' error when converting an int column to varchar in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

This is the code I used:

```
select *
FROM tableA a where cast(columnA as varchar)= 'ABC'  limit 10;
```

However the error i got is:

```
Numeric value 'BCD' is not recognized
```

The weird thing is:

1. I already converted the data type to string.
2. the 'BCD' popped up in error message is not the one I used which is 'ABC'

I also checked the typeof this column, it's all integer.

I wanna get some data  either int or string is fine

Comment: One possibility is the code is connecting to a different database than you expect, especially if you have different environments available. But if you **really** know every value is an integer, why even make this comparison with a non-numeric value that can never succeed?

Comment: Where is the FULL error message? also regarding the tag "SQL" if you hover over that tag please read the text "*Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL*"

Comment: You may need this soon: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above query is not ANSI SQL compliant.